# MATLAB : How to increase the speed of this particular code?

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop

I am basically trying to read 50000 png files (files named 1.png, 2.png....) sequentially and convert them to grayscale one by one. Then I convert these image data to a single vector using reshape function. imresize here reduces the 32*32 image dimension to 8*8. Since the for loop below takes a lot time (~5 to 6 minutes), I am thinking of alternate methods or any optimization methods. I tried matlabpool and parfor from parallel computing toolbox, but since I am working on a isolated computer, its not working for me. Please suggest me some methods or changes in this code.

```
image_Coll = zeros(8*8,50000);

for k = 1:50000
  imageData = imread(strcat('D:\MATLAB_FILES\KAGGLE_CIFAR\train\',num2str(k), '.png'));
  imageData = imresize(imageData,[8 8]);
  imageData = rgb2gray(imageData);
  imageData=reshape(imageData,8*8,1); % 8 * 8 pixels
  image_Coll(:,k)= imageData;
end
```

Comment: I agree with Dennis - [why are you looking for a speed increase](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of speed do you hope to achieve? Personally I don't think that opening 1000 images per minute doesn't qualify as slow.

If you want significant speedups, you may need to think outside the box a bit. Some things I could come up with:

1. Rather than loading 50000 images, try saving them into one or a few bigger (mat) files and loading them from there. Of course this only helps if you need to process the same pics multiple times.
2. In general you can achieve speedups by using vectorization. I don't know whether it is possible, but if you call rgb2gray on a few big images (the concatenation of your original ones) and split up the result it may be much faster than processing each image individually.

Anyway, make sure to use the `profile`, focus on the bottleneck and keep realistic expectations.

Comment: I thought there is some better way to do this. Yes I am a premature programmer.

Answer (score 1):

The most time-consuming part is likely to be `imread`, and there's probably not much you can do about that.

You could reduce time a little by using separate variables within the loop. With your code as it stands, `imageData` is first 32x32, then 8x8, and in the next iteration Matlab has to allocate memory to make `imageData` 32x32 again. You can avoid that using two variables instead of one. Also, `(:)` may be faster than `reshape`:

```
image_Coll = zeros(8*8,50000);

for k = 1:50000
  imageData = imread(strcat('D:\MATLAB_FILES\KAGGLE_CIFAR\train\',num2str(k), '.png'));
  imageData2 = imresize(imageData,[8 8]);
  imageData2 = rgb2gray(imageData2);
  image_Coll(:,k)= imageData2(:);
end
```

Or perhaps

```
image_Coll = zeros(8*8,50000);

for k = 1:50000
  imageData = imread(strcat('D:\MATLAB_FILES\KAGGLE_CIFAR\train\',num2str(k), '.png'));
  imageData2(:,k)= rgb2gray(imresize(imageData,[8 8]));
  image_Coll(:,k)= imageData2(:);
end
```

I don't think this will save you much time, though.

Comment: Oh that is sad. I previously used more variables, then made it like this.